# How can I calculate the shortest path between two 2d vector points in an environment with obstacles?

Tags: search, robotics, a-star, shortest-path-problem, path-finding

I have a 2D plane, with a fixed height and width of 10M. The plane has an agent (or robot) in the point $(1, 2.2)$, and an *electric outlet* in the point $(8.2, 9.1)$. The plane has a series of obstacles.

[image]

Is there an algorithm to find the shortest path between the agent and the goal?

And if the point has a fixed wingspan? For example, that the space between **O** and **N** is smaller than the agent, and then the agent cannot cross?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to solve this kind of problem is to construct a *configuration space*: extruding all the polygonal obstacles by sliding the polygon corresponding to the robot around them ([some slides](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~motionplanning/lecture/Chap3-Config-Space_howie.pdf)).

The exterior vertices of the configuration space can then be used as input to a path-planning algorithm, such as A*.